# How to run existing task scheduler's task (Scheduled Task) using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to run existing task scheduler's task on Windows 10 using Powershell?

I can create, modify, delete tasks on win 10 with powershell.

I know about command line schtasks.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Start-ScheduledTask Cmdlet:

Here is an example:

```
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "ScanSoftware"
```

Please check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/scheduledtasks/start-scheduledtask) link for more information

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that you're referring to schtasks.exe. This command line is the method I've used many times for running a task. Is there a reason to not use this command line utility?

Schtasks /run /tn  should do the trick.